# What is the circuit's logic diagram of a (2-bit binary to decimal) encoder

Tags: logic-gates, encoder, binary

To give a sense of what I am looking for ... this is a the [circuit's logic diagram of a 4-bit binary to decimal encoder](https://www.scribd.com/doc/23119807/4-bit-Binary-to-Decimal-Decoder-BDD). 
[image]

Here is its truthtable
[image]

### Now, **What is the circuit's logic diagram of a 2-bit binary to decimal encoder?**

Comment: You have the truth table right there in front of you. Draw some Karnaugh maps and you will have the answer. What exactly is causing you difficulty with this problem?

Comment: I do disagree. We generally don't like to just give out answers; we prefer to help you learn how to get the answers yourself...otherwise we get into an endless loop of answering the same kind of question over and over again. Maybe you should tell us what you **do know**. Do you know anything about Boolean algebra? How to read a truth table, how to get minterms or a sum-of-products representation from a truthtable?

Comment: I won't draw you the schematic but this should help:
Q0 = (NOT A) AND (NOT B)
Q1 = A AND (NOT B)
Q2 = (NOT A) AND B
Q3 = A AND B

Comment: Okay, it actually wasn't hard at all. Thank you for the help @Stiddily.

Can someone please confirm I did it right? https://gyazo.com/de33900114d50c7ce8ea1c2423da0cdf

Comment: Looks right to me @Sebastian Nielsen. I would definitely advise looking into karnaugh maps as well though. They start off fairly simple and will definitely be necessary once you start building bigger things.

Comment: A device like the one described in the question conventionally is called a *de*coder rather than an [*en*coder](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_encoder); see the page hyperlinked or [en.wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_decoder#1-of-n_decoder), too. (FWIW, I think the Gate level circuit diagram on the Encoder (digital) page questionable.)

Answer (score 0):

it depends which 2 bits you choose out of 4 because you can only get 4 out of 10 decimal equivalent single outputs.

- for a simple reduction from schematic:
- with a pencil or your mind, tick off all the first 4 outputs back to the wired inputs and delete the rest not used.
- it should only require 2 inputs as given in your question
- or easier trace the 1st two bit inputs A,B to the 4 essential  outputs 2^2=4 leaving C,D=0

Since the NAND gates are redundant and two inversions cancel we get.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "tick off"? I think I know, but beginners might not.

Comment: That still seems rather complicated, the easiest would be to just build it from scratch.

Comment: Ok . Then use an eraser with an image editor or start from scratch , whatever is quicker

Comment: I assumed you wanted a quick reduction method from an existing larger scaled solution. This saves time, but you need to learn the fundamentals AND,OR,XOR,NOT with a truth table